# Typehead.js not sending ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, typeahead.js

I want to use typeahead.js with a json file. But when I type into the typeahead input, the ajax request is not send.

**javascript:**

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {
    url: '/users.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(user) { return { name: user }; });
    }
  }
});

users.initialize();

$('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'users',
  displayKey: 'name',
  // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
  // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
  source: users.ttAdapter()
});
```

**rails controller:**

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    @search = User.select :name
    render json: @search
end
```

Comment: I think you should replace "prefetch" by "remote" !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right code to use :
In your **javascript** :

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  remote: {
    url: '/users.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(user) { return { name: user }; });
    }
  }
});
```